# How do I import/install SQLAlchemy-1.1.9 into python?

Tags: python

I am having trouble figuring out how to install it into python so I can import it into my code.
Could someone give a noob a hand?

EDIT: To those saying I need to research, I am currently on a school WIFI connection and many websites are blocked, (YouTube is one of them) and it took a whole minute for the page to load as the school wifi is under heavy load right now.

Comment: Google is your friend here. Do your background research.

Comment: there are lots of tutorials and guides available for installing and working with sqlalchemy. please do enough research before asking in SO.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows very little research effort and the answer could easily be found elsewhere.

Comment: @ChristianDean please read the edit

Comment: @2tbc1887 The rules still apply, regardless of your wifi quality...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pip install it.

```bash
pip install SQLAlchemy
```

Then you can use it like this:

```python
import sqlalchemy
sqlalchemy.__version__ # doctest: +SKIP
```

More detail you can look http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

When you start a new project in python it's better to use `virtualenv`. Google for the instructions on to set up the virtualenv on your operating system. If you use Ubuntu it can be done this way:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualenv
```

After that you need to initialize the virtualenv inside of your project directory:

```
 virtualenv env
```

Then you initialize the virtualenv:

```
 . env/bin/activate
```

After this you can easily install the sql-alchemy:

```
 pip install sqlalchemy
```

If don't need to use virtualenv and you want to install sqlalchemy on your whole system, then you need to install pip first:

```
 sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

And the run from the terminal:

```
 pip install sqlalchemy
```

For Windows and other operating systems you can easily find the instructions. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, how do i make it so i can import it? (you have probs answered this but I'm still confused sorry)

Comment: @2tbc1887,  What operating system are you using?

Comment: Windows 10 (ignore this part just needed more characters)

Comment: Also sorry for late reply, the internet crashed but its way faster now

Comment: @2tbc1887, Please refer to the official installation of virtualenv on Windows http://pymote.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/windows_virtualenv.html. Or look at how to install pip on Windows. Then just run `pip install sqlalchemy`.

Comment: I will as soon as I get it installed incase I need any extra help, as I said earlier, I'm a complete noob

Comment: Ok. found out pip comes preinstalled. however having trouble. where do i run pip install sqlalchemy   ?

Comment: @2tbc1887, In the command line of your Windows.

Comment: So just CMD...?

Comment: C:\Users\2tbc1>pip install sqlalchemy
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.